# I can’t disable show just my code in VSC latest version

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-code, settings

I’m trying to get started on coding and I’m following a tutorial. In the tutorial it shows a lot of other lines than just mine. I saw in the terminal or somewhere that show just my code is enabled. I tried going to settings to disable it but I couldn’t find the option. I went online and tried loads of different solutions. None of them worked. I tried adding the line of code ‘’’,”justMyCode”:false’’’ in ‘’’launch.json’’’ and ‘’’settings.json’’’. It didn’t work. I looked everywhere in debug settings. A lot of sites said go to tools but I can’t find a tools tab anywhere and nothing comes up when I search it in the settings. I’ve tried searching for preferences in settings. Nothing. I’ve also tried looking for exclude code. Nothing is working. Please help.

Comment: Maybe they just typed in more code in the tutorials? Your question is rather unclear to me.

Comment: Some snippet of your code and tutorial link could be helpful to understand your question better.

Comment: the tutorial I'm following= https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGD0vn-QIkg&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR4CtEelGPsmPzlvP7ISPYzR&index=2

The problem is I cant turn just my code off. It doesn't show the system and stuff. I went ahead with tutorial anyway but it shows up when I need to use lists. I can't add a new system